# Need to dynamically create objects that implement the same interface (using Activator.CreateInstance)

Tags: vb.net, object, dynamic, reflection

I cannot figure this out. I want to pass in a GenreID and get a list of objects for that corresponding genre i.e. If I pass in MyGenre.RockAndRoll, I want a list of RockAndRoll objects.

Public Enum MyGenre
                alternative = 0
                rockAndRoll = 1
                country = 2
            End Enum

```
        Public Interface IGenre
            Inherits IDisposable
            Property title As String
            Property artist As String
            Property duration As Decimal
            Property rating As Integer
            Sub Listen()
        End Interface

        Public Class RockAndRoll
            Implements IGenre

            Public Property artist As String Implements IGenre.artist

            Public Property duration As Decimal Implements IGenre.duration

            Public Property rating As Integer Implements IGenre.rating

            Public Property title As String Implements IGenre.title

            Public Sub Listen() Implements IGenre.Listen
                '...
            End Sub
#Region "IDisposable Support"
 '...
#End Region

        End Class

        Public Class Country
            Implements IGenre

            Public Property artist As String Implements IGenre.artist

            Public Property duration As Decimal Implements IGenre.duration

            Public Property rating As Integer Implements IGenre.rating

            Public Property title As String Implements IGenre.title

            Public Sub Listen() Implements IGenre.Listen
                '...
            End Sub
#Region "IDisposable Support"
  '...
#End Region

        End Class


        Public Function GetAlternativeList() As IEnumerable(Of IGenre)
            Return GetIGenreList(MyGenre.alternative)
        End Function

        Public Function GetrockAndRollList() As IEnumerable(Of IGenre)
            Return GetIGenreList(MyGenre.alternative)
        End Function

        Public Function GetIGenreList(p_MyGenre As MyGenre) As IEnumerable(Of IGenre)
            Using db As New OracleDataContext
                Return (From s In db.SongList
                        Where s.Genre= MyGenre _
                        Select CType(Activator.CreateInstance(p_MyGenre.GetGenreType,
                                                               New With {.title = s.title, .artist = p1.artist, etc etc etc}), p_MyGenre.GetGenreTyp)).ToList
            End Using
        End Function


        <Extension()> _
        Private Function GetGenreType(p_formatID As MyGenre) As Type
            Select Case p_formatID
                Case MyGenre.rockAndRoll
                    Return GetType(RockAndRoll)
                Case MyGenre.country
                    Return GetType(PlayawayView)
                Case Else
                    Return Nothing
            End Select
        End Function
```

#

EDIT

#

I would like to add an additional example for clarity. The first one is confusing. Lets look at this from a format perspective.

I want to return a list of products (DVD, CD, Blu-Ray, etc) each format has it's own internal class (for artwork sizing, processing, legality reasons, etc).

```
Class CD -> Implments IProduct
Class DVD -> Implements IProduct
Class BLURAY -> Implements IProduct

i.e. dim MyList = (from p in MyProductTable select p).tolist


returns 4 records. 
(0) 
    title: Motown Unmixed
    artist: Various
    duration: 36:25
    format: CD
    upc: 024543246157
(1)
    title: Classical Bytes - Bach
    artist: Various
    duration: 54:32
    format: CD
    upc: 709387901743
(2)
    title: Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi
    artist: null
    duration: 136.00
    format: DVD
    upc: 883928446172
(3)
    title: Perfect Stranger
    artist: null
    duration: 95.36
    format: BLU
    upc: 043215190627
```

What I want is a list IPRODUCT. This could be done by hitting the database 3 times (for each format type). And appending the results into the IPRODUCT list.

```
dim MyProductList as new List(of IProduct) 

MyProductList.addrange((from p in MyProductTable where p.format = "CD" select new CD with {.title = p.title, etc etc etc}).tolist)

MyProductList.addrange((from p in MyProductTable where p.format = "DVD" select new DVD with {.title = p.title, etc etc etc}).tolist)

MyProductList.addrange((from p in MyProductTable where p.format = "BLU" select new BLURAY with {.title = p.title, etc etc etc}).tolist)
```

I want to consolidate the 3 queries above into one query. This query would return a list of CD, DVD, and BLURAY objects.

Comment: You don't need an `Interface` to enforce properties. If the derived classes are to have them they just need to be marked as `Public` on the base class.

Comment: I agree 100%. My actual code has nothing to do with music.  It's a demonstration I threw together so others can better understand what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simpler way would be to ditch the interface and make an enum with the genre types then you only need one class where you select which genre each class is.

```
Dim query = db.Songlist.Where(Function(s) s.genre = genre).ToList
```